# axios get, if error (or 404), call axios post

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, get, axios

I have an axios call to get a UPC from a dataset.  If it's successful, I'll do something, if it's not found, call axios again to POST.

This is what I have right now, but when it errors (404) when trying to run the get, I get a 422 error.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/products/findOne', {
  "params": {
    "filter": {
      "where": {
        "upc": product.upc
      }
    }
  }
}).then(response => {
  // UPC Found
}).catch(function(error) {
  // UPC Not found
  // Post UPC 
  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/products', {
  //axios stuff here
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I dont believe I am doing this correctly at all... Input?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error [422](https://www.keycdn.com/support/422-unprocessable-entity/) means *unprocessable entity* looks like the API you are requesting is given a 422 instead of 404 if it can't find the record?

Comment: It's giving a 422 in the catch error.  I can run any other functions within that, just not a basic axios call.  Even if ai duplicate a 200 status call, still, 422.  which doesnt make sense.. which also makes me believe I am doing it all wrong lol.

Comment: @RyanJay this really a server error! something is going wrong there. There is nothing wrong with the JavaScript code. So I will check the server logs why it sending 433